# Creating a SQL structure table in R using contents of a dataframe

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

```
#   Create dummy dataframe
dataframe1 <- rbind("a","b","c")

#   Create variable list 
variablelist <- unique(dataframe1[,1])

#   Loop through adding VARCHAR and commas
sql_var_list <- NULL

for(char in seq_along(variablelist)){
  sql_var_list <- paste(sql_var_list,client_variables[char]," VARCHAR,",sep="")
}

#   Remove the final comma
sql_var_list <- substr(sql_var_list, 1, nchar(sql_var_list)-1)

#   Create structure table SQL string
create_strture_table <- paste("CREATE TABLE (",sql_var_list,")",sep="")
```

In the above code I'm using the contents from a column in a dataframe in R to create a structure table that will later be created in redshift. The above code is working, but my method seems a bit untidy, as I'm new to R I wonder if someone can suggest a better approach?

Comment: Don't need any loops or additional variables, just do `paste0("CREATE TABLE (", paste(dataframe1, collapse = " VARCHAR, "), " VARCHAR)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a combination of `paste` and `paste0`, as suggested by David Arenburg in the comments:

```
paste0("CREATE TABLE (", 
       paste(dataframe1, collapse = " VARCHAR, "), 
       " VARCHAR)")
# [1] "CREATE TABLE (a VARCHAR, b VARCHAR, c VARCHAR)"
```